# Using DartLang to comunicate via Serial port

Tags: serial-port, dart, rxtx

I want to use DartLang to communicate with Arduino by Serial Port, not over TCP/ip.
I've found [DartLang chrome package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/chrome) and [Chrome Serial reference](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/serial), this is the solution ? Or there are some other solution to use Serial Port with DartLang?

Comment: As far as I know the chrome package only makes the Chrome serial API (JavaScript) available to Dart. I guess you need to build a Dart native extension.

Comment: I found this library on github -- didn't test it -- maybe it can help: [SerialPort](https://github.com/nfrancois/SerialPort)

Comment: thanks to both, second solution is exactly what has described @ Günter Zöchbauer...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit**: https://pub.dev/packages/dart_serial_port was mentioned in the comments which is much more recent and uses Dart FFI.

--

Nicolas François has built a native Dart VM extension that does this:

https://github.com/nfrancois/SerialPort

You'll need to compile it yourself (requires `gcc`, `make`, `pub`):

There's not a huge amount of info on how to use it, but there are [some tests](https://github.com/nfrancois/serial_port/blob/master/test/serial_port_test.dart) and the [dart class](https://github.com/nfrancois/SerialPort/blob/master/lib/src/serial_port_impl.dart) that should be useful:

- [open](https://github.com/nfrancois/SerialPort/blob/1186e4aba486f0b63b0e3bbbf8beb36ccfea62f4/lib/src/serial_port_impl.dart#L28)
- [close](https://github.com/nfrancois/SerialPort/blob/1186e4aba486f0b63b0e3bbbf8beb36ccfea62f4/lib/src/serial_port_impl.dart#L47)
- [write](https://github.com/nfrancois/SerialPort/blob/1186e4aba486f0b63b0e3bbbf8beb36ccfea62f4/lib/src/serial_port_impl.dart#L65)
- [onRead](https://github.com/nfrancois/SerialPort/blob/1186e4aba486f0b63b0e3bbbf8beb36ccfea62f4/lib/src/serial_port_impl.dart#L82)

Looks like you'd use it something like this:

```dart
var serial =  new SerialPort(dummySerialPort.path);
serial.onRead.listen((s) => print('Got: $s'));
serial.open()
  .then((_) => serial.write("Hello"))
  //.then((_) => serial.close());
```

Comment: Since this answer is from 6 years ago I thought I'd update with another option that is available now: https://pub.dev/packages/dart_serial_port which uses Dart's new FFI.

Comment: Nowdays there's the https://pub.dev/packages/libserialport. Also for flutter girls and boys a wrapper around it: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_libserialport